# Regex look ahead assertion picks up unwanted data

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

**Here's my regex:**

```
((?<="StartDate":")\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=.+"Status":"(B|C)"))
```

I am trying to filter the JSON below to show only the start date value of records with Status = B or C but my regex returns all statuses including those with Status not equal to B or C.

I used a regex testing site and saved my current progress here:
https://regexr.com/58314

**JSON:**
[{"RowNumber":1,"PeriodNumber":0,"StartDate":"2023-10-18","EmployeeCompany":"0A","FirmName":"Company 1","EmpStatus":"X","TKGroup":"AR","Status":"A","StatusDesc":"In Progress"},{"RowNumber":2,"PeriodNumber":0,"StartDate":"2021-01-01","EmployeeCompany":"0A","FirmName":"Company 2","EmpStatus":"Y","TKGroup":"AR","Status":"B","StatusDesc":"Submitted"},{"RowNumber":3,"PeriodNumber":0,"StartDate":"2020-01-01","EmployeeCompany":"0A","FirmName":"Company 3","EmpStatus":"Z","TKGroup":"AR","Status":"C","StatusDesc":"Rejected"},{"RowNumber":4,"PeriodNumber":0,"StartDate":"2019-10-18","EmployeeCompany":"0A","FirmName":"Company 4","EmpStatus":"A","TKGroup":"AR","Status":"A","StatusDesc":"In Progress"}]

**Expected: (both dates falls the criteria where Status = B or C))**
2021-01-01
2020-01-01

**Actual: (first date (2023-10-18) should not be captured as its status is = A, I was able to eliminate the other date with Status = A but not the first one.)**
2023-10-18
2021-01-01
2020-01-01

Comment: Welcome to SO, please explain in words what you actual problem is.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using regex for this, instead of loading the JSON and treating it as a proper data structure? What language are you trying to solve this task in? Please have a look at the [mcve] and [ask] help pages.

Comment: This is for LoadRunner, there is a function to incorporate regex to correlate the response, I am exploring regex as it is flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a minor change.

```
((?<="StartDate":")\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?=","Status":"(B|C)"))
```

Replaced `.+` with `",`